Hi i have a direct drive Ryobi table saw
When I switch it on it makes a screeching noise and when I try a test cut the blade stops but the motor keeps going. I removed the blade and with out a blade it sound normal

Read the fine manual and put the blade on properly.

Your blade was not anchored to the motor tight enough.  Check the owner's manual for the proper stack of washers and torque recommendations.

I did a test to see if the blade is moving made a mark on the arbour and blade after switching it on and a test cut that stops the blade I switched off to check if the blade moved and it did not move
